# Can't Increment A Variable inside OnClickListener with an If Condition

Tags: android, if-statement, onclicklistener

I have an OnClickListener and I can't increment my counter inside it if there is a Condition

```
           img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick (View v){
           if(name1=="heart"){
               correct++;
           }
       }
   });
```

correct increments if there is no if condition. how can I increment it with the condition. Please Help.

Comment: use `equals` instead of `==` to compare strings

Comment: Is the line with the increment being reached?

Comment: Is 'correct' declared at the class level?

Comment: i forgot the equals functionality for strings. that solved my problem. thanks krsteeve!

Answer (score 2):

Like krsteeve said, in Java, you must use the member "equals" for string comparison.

```
    myString.equals("heart")
```